# Why does urxvt display this box drawing glyph differently?

Tags: fonts, unicode, rxvt, konsole

I'm switching to `urxvt` and noticed something on the way. I use `zsh` and [`powerlevel10k`](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) with it. The powerline, if that's what it's called, is being differently on `urxvt`, even though both `konsole` and `urxvt` are using the same font, *Meslo LGS NF*.
Below are the screenshots of the glyhp, the leftmost one:
**urxvt**:
[image: urxvt]

**konsole**:
[image: konsole]

These are the glyphs: ╭─ (U+256D) and ╰ (U+2570).

As you can see, `konsole` display are straight bar but `urxvt` shows it as curved. How can I fix this? And more importantly, what's causing this?

My config:

```
! Set depth to make transparency work.
URxvt*depth: 32

! Custom urxvt settings.
URxvt.scrollBar:    false
URxvt.font:         xft:MesloLGS NF:size=13:antialias=true
URxvt.boldFont:
URxvt*letterSpace:  -2
```

Comment: The ╭ character in MesloLGS NF is curved, but the curve is invisible at smaller sizes. For me the character starts looking curved in Konsole at size 14. Exactly when the curve is more than one pixel may depend on your screen resolution and antialiasing type. The curve in urxvt a lot larger than it should, I don't know why. Maybe it's substituting another font? (But it shouldn't be.)

Comment: It's supposed to be curved (the Unicode name says ***arc*** (see [this](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+256D)).

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't it be curved in konsole too?